# Google appengine queries fail with namespacing

Tags: google-app-engine, namespaces, google-cloud-datastore

I am introducing namespacing into my application, but I have run into an issue with one of my existing queries that performs the following operation in order to determine whether or not an entity exists for the given key.

```
// c is of type context.Context
c, _ = appengine.Namespace(c, "name")

k := datastore.NewKey(c, "Kind", "", id, nil)

q := datastore.NewQuery("Kind").Filter("__key__ =", k).KeysOnly()
keys, err := q.GetAll(c, nil)
```

When this command is executed with a namespace applied to the context, it gives back the following error:

`datastore_v3 API error 1: __key__ filter namespace is  but query namespace is db`

I could just use a `Get` query instead, but I don't need to actually retrieve the entity at all. Plus, keys-only queries are free!

**Update**

It seems that all queries are failing after I have introduced namespacing. The documentation doesn't mention any sort of special treatment for the indices:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/multitenancy/multitenancy

Comment: Are you using the same context when creating the key? Looks like they don't share the same namespace.

Comment: They are being created in the same location, I will update the code to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

"By default, the datastore uses the current namespace for datastore requests. The API applies this current namespace to datastore.Key objects when they are created. Therefore, you need to be careful if an application stores Key objects in serialized forms, since the namespace is preserved in those serializations."

**Using namespaces with the Datastore**
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/multitenancy/multitenancy#Go_Using_namespaces_with_the_Datastore